# Column Default Value Settings disappear after site collection restore

Tags: restore, metadata

I have restored a site collection and for some reason the column default value settings have all disappeared. Is this a known problem with SPSite-restore? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My Powershell restore command had a lower case site collection path whereas the backed up site collection was upper case. Once I corrected it and did a new restore with the correct case the defaults became visible in the restored site collection. Bit of a trap for a beginner like me.